# Why should the nonce for Android in-app billing generated on the server?

Tags: android, security, in-app-purchase, google-play, nonce

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_best_practices.html

As the best practices documentation suggests, I want my server to perform signature verification tasks for in-app billing. which brings me to this clause about nonces:

> Also, if you are performing nonce verification on a server, make sure that you generate the nonces on the server.

I know that the nonce i pass in with the purchase request will come back as part of the purchase data under `developerPayload` for extra verification. Is it not enough for the client to generate a unique nonce using SecureRandom? - since I will pass the purchase data back to the server for verification anyway, it will store the client-generated nonces as well to filter out replay attacks.

Why do I have to "make sure" that nonces are generated on the server? It just seems to complicate process because now the app needs to request a nonce from the server before any in-app purchase.

The only extremely unlikely situation I can think of that it may be useful is to prevent instances when SecureRandom on the client generates a nonce that has already been used on the server. Even then isn't such situation easily identified by cross checking with `orderId`, which should be unique itself anyway?

Comment: Yes you are right that it will be an extra burdon to fetch nonce from server but if you put it on server no one can see your logic of generating it via reverse engg.

Comment: @Ankit what is the big problem even if they reverse engineer the nonce generation? It will be random anyway so even I won't know what nonce I will be generating. As long as the purchase data contains a valid signature from Google Play, haven't they paid for the purchase no matter what the nonce is? (Unless Google Play itself has been compromised, which means I'm stuffed anyway :S)

Comment: I will be keeping a list of used up nonces so they can't keep claiming extra credits on my system by reposting same purchase data over and over again. Then again, couldn't I just store the `orderId` from Google to achieve the same thing? Maybe the nonce is designed for apps without a backend and a user/email/mobile no. to associate purchases with.

Comment: nonce is use to protect reply attack. Please have a look at http://security.stackexchange.com/q/4067 i think this will give answer to you question.

Comment: you can also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/10517459/1221797

Comment: As I already mentioned in my original question, I know it's supposed to stop replay attack, but I don't see the point of it being server-generated. Or not even needed if you store all the purchase data on a server DB since orderId should be unique anyway.

Comment: if someone do reverse engineering they can store the response coming from google and later on send to your server and your server will always verify that because it will be having true order id. so if u add a nonce which is unique for each transaction generated on server it will help you to stop such attacks.

Comment: Except that the tampered response won't have a valid signature attached to it. They will need to know the private key stored in Google's server to sign the purchase data with. I guess the nonce will act like salt and make it impossible to guess the private key.

Comment: Yes you are right it will act as salt.

Comment: I know I'm late to this party. Just want to add my 2 cents.If you generate nonces on the client, store them in the server when used, and proceed to check if the nonce was used before you end up with a huge table of used and useless nonces. If your app grows big and converts a lot, your nonces tables will grow bigger and bigger. Not that it will be something unbearable, but generating the nonces on the server has the advantage that you only store the ones that are in use, then delete them when used. That would make the nonces table way smaller and manageable.

Comment: Also, you can delete the nonces if they have not been used after a while. Even change the algorithm that generates them in the first place, just to add noise.